# Cannot Inject reusable component to different components in the same level in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a simple Angular2 Application, which contains `App`, `P1`, `P2`, `Child` in total 4 components, where `App` uses `P1` and `P2`, and both `P1` and `P2` uses `Child`.

Here is the code:

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<div> child <div>',
})
export class ChildCmp {}

@Component({ 
  selector: 'p1',
  template: '<div> P1: <child></child></div>',
  directives:[ChildCmp],
})
export class P1Cmp {}

@Component({ 
  selector: 'p2',
  template: '<div> P2: <child></child><child></child></div>',
  directives:[ChildCmp],
})
export class P2Cmp {}

@Component({ 
  selector: 'my-test',
  template: '<p1></p1><p2></p2>',
  directives:[P1Cmp, P2Cmp],
})
export class TestApp {}

bootstrap(TestApp);
```

The **index.html** to trigger the app is plain `<my-test></my-test>` with all required libs of Angular2.

You can check the demo in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kir7QmwhSsIuAU5IrnMh?p=info), console log shows

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: viewFactory_ChildCmp0 is not a function
```

This app breaks in Angular2 Initialization, once I put the `Child` into the both `P1` and `P2`, then it breaks.

Any idea why it breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use unminified version for Angular 2 beta.1, it is well documented that they have problem with .min.js version. Second, avoid beta.1 for now, you example work perfectly in beta.0

Comment: Just tired with unminified version, it still breaks, and it is really working with beta.0, so it is a bug in beta.01? Thanks!

Comment: Yet, it is. Your code is perfectly fine. They will release new Angular 2 version each week from now till release... Stay tuned.